# Fetch Results from All tables in SpringBoot JPA Repository

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to fetch data from all below tables using `JOIN` query for particular `productType` and `Sizes` (column in two diff tables).
I am unable to get the desired result so some guidance would be very helpful.

Please find the details below what I have tried till now.

PK: Primary Key, FK: Foreign Key.
Following is the table structure with tables(mentioned) below has `OneToOne` mapping to another table.

```
**MC_Product_Type**:
  prod_type_id (PK), 
  prod_type,
  description
|
|OnetoOne
| 
**MC_Set_Rules**:
  set_id (PK),
  prod_type_id (FK),
  set_name,
  set_type,
  condition
|
|OneToOne
|
**MC_Size_Rules**:
  prod_rule_id (PK),
  prod_type,
  Sizes,
  set_id (FK),
  min_qty,
  dimension
|
|OneToOne
| 
**MC_Product_Rules**: 
   prod_rule_id (FK),
   prod_type, 
   allowed_type, 
   availability, 
   prod_label, 
   locations
```

Entity Classes:

```
@Table(name = "MC_Product_Type")
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@ApiModel
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ProductType {
    @Id
    private int prodTypeId;
    private String prodType;
    private String description;

     @OneToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="prodTypeId", referencedColumnName="prodTypeId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
     private SetRules setRules;
}


@Table(name = "MC_Set_Rules")
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
public class SetRules {
    

    @Id
    private int setId;
    private int prodTypeId;
    private String setName;
    private String setType;
    private String condition;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="setId", referencedColumnName="setId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private SizeRulesEntity sizeRules;
}


@Table(name = "MC_Size_Rules")
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter

public class SizeRulesEntity {
    @Id
    private int prodRuleId;
    private String prodType;
    private String sizes;
    private int setId;
    private int minQty;
    private String dimension;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="prodRuleId", referencedColumnName="prodRuleId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private ProductRules productRules;
}


@Table(name = "MC_Product_Rules")
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
public class ProductRules {
    @Id
    private  int prodRuleId;
    private String prodType;
    private String allowedType;
    private String availability;
    private String prodLabel;
    private String locations;

}.
```

Repository:

```
Value for prod_type = "ELLACUST"
Value for Sizes = "XS","S","M","L","XL"
```

I used these below queries(one by one) , based on prod_type and Size I need to get data from all the tables.

Note: Sizes is not part of table `MC_Product_Type`.  Data team has informed if they include sizes in this table it will be a redundant data. so sizes is part of `MC_Size_Rules` table.

I am trying to pass prod_type and sizes dynamically in first two query but getting results only for size 'XS' which is value for 1st row in table `MC_Size_Rules` even though if I pass other sizes values.

In third query, I am getting exception saying sizes is not part of `ProductType`.

I need help on what should I change in entity classes, mappings or in query to get data from all the tables when `prod_type` and correct sizes is passed.

```
public interface ProductRulesRepository extends JpaRepository <ProductType, String> {
    @Query("SELECT pt FROM ProductType pt JOIN pt.setRules s ON pt.prodTypeId = s.prodTypeId JOIN s.sizeRules sr ON s.setId = sr.setId JOIN sr.productRules pr ON sr.prodRuleId = pr.prodRuleId  where pt.prodType = :prodType AND pt.setRules.sizeRules.sizes = :sizes")
    ProductType findAllByProdTypeAndSizes(String prodType, String sizes);

    @Query("SELECT pt FROM ProductType pt JOIN pt.setRules s ON pt.prodTypeId = s.prodTypeId JOIN s.sizeRules sr ON s.setId = sr.setId JOIN sr.productRules pr ON sr.prodRuleId = pr.prodRuleId  where pt.prodType = ?1 AND pt.setRules.sizeRules.sizes = ?2"))

    @Query("SELECT pt FROM ProductType pt JOIN pt.setRules s ON pt.prodTypeId = s.prodTypeId JOIN s.sizeRules sr ON s.setId = sr.setId JOIN sr.productRules pr ON sr.prodRuleId = pr.prodRuleId")
    ProductType findAllByProdTypeAndSizes(String prodType, String sizes);
```

> exception : sizes is not defined in ProductType

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are misusing `@Query` annotation your variable interpolation is wrong cf "`?2` you should use it like this

```
@Query("select from User u where u.id = :id")
findUserById(@Param("id") String id)
```

Second: the return type of your methods are wrong, you are selecting multiple rows so your retrun type should be a collection

third: Spring provides you with a feature called Spring named queries. It allows spring guessing the associated sql from the method's name

and finally you can try something like this

```
 Collection<ProductType> findByProdTypeAndSizeRulesSizes(String prodType, String sizes);
```

hibernate orm will handle fetches for you the associated data in the related objects (@OneToOne relations)